# Is there such a thing as a join() aggregate function that concatentates field values at a specific character?

Tags: aggregate-functions, aggregate, teradata

Let's say I have a table called `cities` with fields of `state` and `city`.  Data looks like this:

```
State     City
Ohio      Eaton
Ohio      Columbus
Ohio      Dayton
Ohio      Greenville
New York  New York
New York  Albany
New York  Syracuse
```

I would like to be able to do this:

```
select state, join(city,',') from cities
group by state
```

...to return this:

```
State     City
Ohio      Eaton,Columbus,Dayton,Greenville
New York  New York,Albany,Syracuse
```

Would I need to create some crazy UDF for this?  If there's not a function, is there a way to apply some SQL magic to make this happen?

Comment: So basically the equivalent of mysql's group_concat() function? Found this: http://forums.teradata.com/forum/analytics/concatenate-vertically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive CTE should be able to accomplish this. I mocked up the sequence number to reset for each State. You may have to tweak this based on your actual table but it should at least get you thinking in the right direction. (Similar to what Marc B linked on the Teradata Forum but hopefully this is easier to read.)

```
WITH RECURSIVE city_list (state, cities, seq) AS
(
  SELECT s.state
       , s.city
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY State ORDER BY State, City) AS seq
  FROM   states s
  QUALIFY  seq = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.cities ||’, ’|| s.city
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY State, City) AS seq
  FROM   city_list c, states s
  WHERE  s.seq = c.seq + 1
    AND  s.state = c.state
)
SELECT r.state, r.cities
FROM   city_list r
WHERE  r.seq = (SELECT MAX(h.seq) FROM city_list h 
                WHERE h.state = r.state 
                GROUP BY h.state)
;
```